# SFML - Vector with custom class doesn't load textures

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I'm trying to make a vector of a custom class (Called "WorldObject").

The WorldObject class is defined here:

```
class WorldObject : public sf::Drawable {
private:
    sf::Texture _texture;

    int spriteWidth;
    int spriteHeight;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

public:
    WorldObject(std::string filename, int width, int height, int _xPos, int _yPos);
    sf::Sprite _sprite;
    ~WorldObject();
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

    sf::FloatRect getCollisionBox();

};
```

The initialization class is defined here:

```
WorldObject::WorldObject(std::string filename, int width, int height, int _xPos, int _yPos) {

    if(_texture.loadFromFile(filename)) {
        _sprite.setTexture(_texture);
    }

    spriteWidth = width;
    spriteHeight = height;

    xPos = _xPos;
    yPos = _yPos;
    _sprite.setPosition(xPos, yPos);

}
```

And the vector code is defined here (It is a `vector<WorldObject>`):

```
worldObjects.push_back({name, width, height, x, y});
```

I've also used `worldObjects.push_back(WorldObject(name, width, height, x, y))`;

where name is the filename (In this case, test_object.png), width is the width of the object (192 px), height is the height of the object (192 px), x is the x position (300) and y is the y position (400) in the SFML window (800px, 600px).

I'm trying to load test_object.png. For some kind of reason, it ALWAYS ends up creating a white square instead, in the correct position and with the right dimensions, though.

I can't figure out why this happens. I've tried passing "name" by reference, by value, trying to use a `vector<Texture>` and substituting filename's `std::string` type by a `sf::Texture` one without any avail.

Thanks @super for making me remember that the Texture doesn't load and that the file name is correct and that the file exists

Comment: Is the texture loading succesfully?

Comment: Well, no. The texture doesn't load

Comment: Have you checked that the filename is correct, and that the file actually exists in the right location? How do you run the program?

Comment: Yes, the filename is correct. I forgot to mention it. I've checked like 5 times. Thanks

Comment: And what about if the file in the correct place/folder? Normally the file should be in the same folder as the executable. But that depends on how you run it.

Comment: Sorry. I also meant that the file is in the correct place and that it exists and that it is of a supported file type. (I've used another WorldObject (using the same file) outside the vector and it loaded correctly)

Comment: Read [white square problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php). Store `WorldObject` in smart pointer (unique_ptr or shared_ptr), or provide copy constructor/assignment operator which makes deep copy of texture.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved it! Thanks, @rafix07!

this

```
worldObjects.push_back({name, width, height, x, y});
```

line should be substituted by:

```
WorldObject *tmp = new WorldObject(name, width, height, x, y);
worldObjects.push_back(*tmp);
```

Remember to delete the object when it's not needed to reduce risk of memory leaks.